# How to add custom code snippets in VSCode?

Tags: code-snippets, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to add custom code snippets in Visual Studio Code? And if so, how? VSCode is based on Atom, so it should be possible.

Comment: [Adding Snippets to VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets)

Comment: you can also go to Preferences > User Snippets, and then select the language you want to create a snippet in.

Comment: Is there really a relationship between VS Code as Atom *other than* the fact that they both use Electron under the hood?

Comment: Use [codessnippet](https://codessnippet.com) service to do that. You can create custom snippets, edit and sync with codessnippet cli all snippets at once, just pulling from server!

Comment: I want to add a webpage link in the description, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 213):

1. Hit > <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and type snippets
2. Select **Preferences: Configure User Snippets**
3. Choose the language type for which you want to add the custom snippet in the vscode inputbox
4. vscode has comments to explain on how to add a snippet, as described on :> [**vsdoc**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) or you can follow the next link with a short guide:

---

Lets say, we want to open custom snippets for the language GO. Then we can do:

1. Hit > <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
2. Type: go.json + <kbd>enter</kbd> And you land on the custom snippet page

> Snippets are defined in a JSON format and stored in a per-user (languageId).json file. For example, Markdown snippets go in a markdown.json file.

---

Using tools:

- [Snippet Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenfangdu.snippet-generator) extension (recommended)
- [Online snippet generator](https://snippet-generator.app/)

Comment: snippet generator is very helpful

Comment: Can I include external snippet files instead of creating a new one? I have a bunch of snippets written for Visual Studio that I would like to import to VSCode. Of course I would need to convert them to json format first.

Comment: tip: when writing snippets, you must use `\t` for tabs or else there will be an error

Answer (score 105):

Option 1 - Use the [Snippet Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenfangdu.snippet-generator) extension.

It supports code to JSON conversion with optional `scope` support and space to `\t` conversion.

Demo:

[image: Demo]

Option 2 - Another extension is [snippet-creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator) (deprecated).

After installing it, all you have to do is to :

1. Select the code that you want to make a snippet.
2. Right-click on it and select "Command Palette"(or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
3. Write "Create Snippet".
4. Choose the type of files needed to be watched to trigger your snippet shortcut.
5. Choose a snippet shortcut.
6. Choose a snippet name.

Option 3 - check this [website](https://snippet-generator.app/). you can generate snippets for vs code, sublime text, and atom.

Once snippet being generated on this site. Go to the respective IDE's snippet file and paste the same. For example for a JS snippet in VS code go to File->preference->user snippet then it opens javascript.json file then paste the snippet code from an above site inside this and we are good to go.

Comment: This is such an awesome tool! I couldn't stomach writing out a custom html boilerplate snippet having to quote and escape each line, so this is really the answer I was looking for.

Comment: The snippet Generator link is broken. Please follow this link: https://snippet-generator.app/

Comment: For us VSCodium/Open-VSX users, [Snippets Manager](https://open-vsx.org/extension/zjffun/snippetsmanager) may be an alternative to manual install.

Answer (score 38):

You can check out this video for a quick short tutorial

https://youtu.be/g1ouTcFxQSU

Go to **File --> Preferences --> User Snippets**. Select your preferred language.
Now type the following code to make a for loop snippet:

```
  "Create for loop":{
    "prefix": "for",
    "body":[
      "for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)",
      "{",
      "   //code goes here",
      "}"
    ],
   "description": "Creates a for loop"
  }
```

You are done.
Type "for" in the editor and use the first prediction.

***SHORTCUT***

1. install [snippet-creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator) extension (now deprecated).
2. Highlight the code that you need to make snippet.
3. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type "Create snippet" on the command palette and
   press ENTER.
4. select language for which you want to create snippet(eg:-CPP), then type 
   snippet name, type snippet shortcut and then type snippet description.
   You are now good to go.
   Type the snippet shortcut in the editor that you entered in step 4, and select the
    prediction (if no prediction comes press ctrl+space) that comes first.

Hope this helps :)

Note: goto File->Preferences->User Snippets. Then select the language in which you
created the snippet. You will find the snippet there.

Comment: How to add double quotes inside the snippet?

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes with a <backslash> like this: `\"`

Comment: [Worth mentioning](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets): "_Additionally, the body of the example above has three placeholders (listed in order of traversal): `${1:array}`, `${2:element}`, and `$0`. You can quickly jump to the next placeholder with Tab, at which point you may edit the placeholder or jump to the next one. The string after the colon `:` (if any) is the default text, for example element in `${2:element}`_"

Answer (score 37):

As of **version 0.10.6** you can add custom snippets. Read the documentation on [Creating your Own Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets).
You can find/create custom snippets by placing the json file in `C:\Users\<yourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets`.
For example, a custom javascript snippets would be in a `\snippets\javascript.json`

You can also publish you snippets which is a really neat feature as well. John Papa created a nice angular + typescript snippet you can download as an extension in the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/#VSCode).

Here is an example snippet taken for the documentation on a javascript for loop:

```
"For Loop": {
    "prefix": "for",
    "body": [
        "for (var ${index} = 0; ${index} < ${array}.length; ${index}++) {",
        "\tvar ${element} = ${array}[${index}];",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "For Loop"
},
```

Where

- `For Loop` is the snippet name
- `prefix` defines a prefix used in the IntelliSense drop down. In this case for.
- `body` is the snippet content. 
  Possible variables are:

  - $1, $2 for tab stops
  - ${id} and ${id:label} and ${1:label} for variables
  - Variables with the same id are connected.
- `description` is the description used in the
  IntelliSense drop down

Comment: They really need some kind of multi-line string literal syntax or a way to pull the body into a separate file. Quoting and escaping every single line is craz.

Answer (score 14):

You can add custom scripts, go to `File --> Preferences --> User Snippets`. Select your preferred language.

If you choose Javascript you can see default custom script for `console.log(' ');` like this:

```
"Print to console": {
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
        "console.log('$1');",
        "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
},
```

Comment: How to add double quotes inside the snippet?

Answer (score 11):

There's a VSCode Plugin called: [snippet-creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator) (now deprecated).

After installing it , all you have to do is to:

1. Select the code that you want to make it a snippet.
2. Right click on it and select "Command Palette"(or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
3. Write "Create Snippet".
4. Choose type of files needed to be watched to trigger your snippet shortcut.
5. Choose a snippet shortcut.
6. Choose a snippet name.

That's All.

Note : if you want to edit your snippets , you will find them in [fileType].json
Example : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> , then select "javascript.json"

Answer (score 7):

I tried by adding snippets in javascriptreact.json but it didn't worked for me.

I tried adding snippets into global scope, and it's working like charm.

```
FILE --> Preferences --> User snippets
```

here select `New Global Snippets File`, give name javas`criptreact.code-snippets`.

For other languages you can name like [your_longuage].code-snippets

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is an undocumented feature as of now but is coming soon. There is a folder you can add them to and they will appear, but it may change (its undocumented for a reason).

Best advice is to add this to the uservoice site and wait til its final. But it is coming.

Answer (score 4):

On MacOS:

1. Open the VSCode
2. **Code** -> **Preferences** -> **User Snippets**
3. Search for "python" (or any language)
4. Write your snippet like this:

```json
{
    "Write pdb": {
        "prefix": "pdb",
        "body": [
            "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "Write pdb.set_trace() to debug Python scripts"
    }
}
```

5. Save the file with `command + S`.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode introduce this in version 0.5, [see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editingevolved#_snippets).
Snippet syntax follows the [TextMate snippet syntax](https://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets) and can write in User Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather not deal with writing your snippets in JSON, check out [Snipster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snipster). It lets you write snippets as you would write the code itself - not having to wrap each line in quotes, escape characters, add meta information, etc.

It also lets you *write once, publish anywhere*. So you can use your snippet in VS Code, Atom, and Sublime, plus more editors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a real answer (as some have answered above), but if you're interested in creating custom code snippets for other people, you can create extensions using yeoman and npm (which by default comes along with NodeJS) . NOTE: This is only for creating snippets for other's systems. But it also works for you too! Except you need JS code for whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom scripts, go to File --> Preferences --> User Snippets. Select your preferred language.

Like mine code is go, I do it as below:

```
"channel code": {
        "prefix": "make_",
        "body": [
            "${1:variable} := make(chan ${2:type}, ${3:channel_length})",
            "$4"
        ]
    }
```

explanation: $1 will take your tabs & to give hints what are those tabs values, we make it like `${1:some_variable}` which could give us hints what are those

I hope, it helps!