# Using custom code snippets (live templates) with a Flutter app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, live-templates

In online tutorials I see people type a few characters that can quickly expand to code snippets. That would save a lot of boilerplate code. How do I do that in Android Studio for Flutter development?

Comment: For VS Code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29995863/12349734

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Android Studio go to **Settings (Preferences on Mac) > Editor > Live Templates**.

Expand the Flutter option. You should see some live templates already defined. To create a new one click the `+` add button on the right and choose Live templates.

[image]

Add an abreviation that you can use in code. Also write a description. Then paste in the code that you want to auto insert. Finally, where it says "Define" choose Dart from the list. Then choose OK.

[image]

If there are any variable names that you want to fill in later you can surround them with `$` signs like `$NAME$`.

## Example

Whenever I want to test some widget, I make a new app with a clean layout, none of those comments and extra widgets. Here is a live template that is just a basic starting layout.

I called the abbreviation `basiclayout` and the code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My App')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Now I can just start typing `basiclayout` to get all that code inserted automatically. I could have replaced the `My App` string or the `BodyWidget` name with a `$NAME$` variable if I wanted to choose a new name every time.

## See also

- [Documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/android-studio#live-templates)