# Visual Studio Code Snippets

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am just wondering how do I create my own custom snippets in visual studio code to make my workflow more productive. This one is specifically for linking my bootstrap at the start of each HTML website.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode

Comment: read the VSC docs about snippets, on the site where you downloaded VSC

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to generate your own snippets is to use an [online generator](https://snippet-generator.app/)

After you created your snippet:

1. Download/install/open VSCode.
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+p or F1 to open the search bar.
3. Type `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`.
4. Open the `language_of_your_choice.json` file.
5. Copy/paste the full json code that you made in the online generator into your VSCode `language_of_your_choice.json`  file.
6. Save and close. You're done!