# Flutter : Quick way to convert 50+ model classes to supports json_serializable

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, nsjsonserialization

I am newbie for Flutter. I have just created sample application using JSON Parsing.

Before I have done it using manual classes but currently I have changed my code to [**json_serializable**](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and you can check the [difference](https://github.com/pratikbutani/FlutterPinCodeFinder/commit/1fa0e8171d1c4cc9cba97676e4242461ba0bde4f#diff-d773753cadc33ed451729e66bb030c58274479986455b6690b4fe4849e7c25ff) here.

It is okay for one or two model class which you need to change with **fromJson** and **toJson** methods but What to do when our project has 50+ model classes.

*Any idea to write all the classes with easy way?*

Do let me know If you need other information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an automated way built to do this. You are going to have to do the changes manually.

To make it easier, you can create a snippet in vscode to generate the new **toJson** and **fromJson** methods
[How to add custom code snippets in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode)

But as the variable names are different from the JSON keys, you will need to add that by yourself.