# PHP intellisense without writing the <?php tag

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have recently switched from Atom to VScode and is looking for a feature that I am not able to find.

In Atom, if I start writing `fore` (to start a foreach loop) in a php file it suggests foreach, and hitting enter outputs this:

```
<?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value): ?>
  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I write `<?php fore` and hits enter on the suggestion it outputs me this:

```
<?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
  // code...
}
```

In VScode, writing `fore` only returns the word "foreach" when outputting the suggestion.
However if I write `<?php fore` it suggests a foreach loop and that gives me this output:

```
<?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
  # code...
}
```

Is there any way to obtain the first solution from Atom in VScode core or with an extension?

Comment: You can do it with custom user snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode

Comment: Okay - I assume that will work - just thought there might be some setting somewhere to make this work for foreach, for, if etc. statements :)