# Vue.js - when creating new Vue File pass automatically name attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, automation, vue-component

I am searching for a way when creating new Vue.js files to pass automatically the [name](https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#name) attribute.

For example, when I create a new Vue file with name `Test.vue`, to generate this automatically:

```
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Test',
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

To add the name attribute based on the file name creation.
Is there any automated way in order to stop adding this manually every time I create Vue file?

Thanks!

Comment: Which text editor do you use? if you use Webstorm or PHPStorm you can use it simply a plugin

Comment: I'm using vs code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at this: **[Custom snippets in VS Code](https://blog.usman-s.me/how-to-create-custom-emmet-snippets-in-vs-code)**. I do not know a way how to **invoke** a script on **creation of a file**, but you could choose a keybinding like "default" which would create a snippet as you wish.

To my knowledge, it would even be possible to set where the cursor will end up, so that you would still have to type the filename manually, but it would immensely speed up your workflow.

You may find more information on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode), or take a look at the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) to this topic

Comment: These are nice ideas and this can be achieved  in a limited extend without fully automating. From the examples I find you can pass the name attribute but not predefined and you have to write it every time still