# Is there a way to make a multipage snippet in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am currently working in react js, and to work with css modules, every-time I make new component and I have to make corresponding css module file. I want snippet to make both files. Is there any way?

Comment: You can [add multiple code-snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995863/how-to-add-custom-code-snippets-in-vscode) in VS-code, but only past one into one file at a time.

Comment: Maybe you should research for [react scaffolder vs-code](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vs-code+react+scaffolder). A _scaffolder_ is a tool or plugin that helps you creating a project or multiple files for it.

Comment: you might use [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) to create an action that based on the main file to generate the other files, maybe [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) could be a solution